# Como esperar resposta do usuario?

Tags: java

Olá, eu estou fazendo um jogo Genius, aquele que é preciso selecionar as cores na ordem certa...

E estou com certa dificuldade na parte da vez do jogador...

```
 public void jogadorJoga(){


}
```

Nesse método eu preciso fazer com que o programa espere o usuário apertar o botão, e assim verificar se a cor selecionada está correta, porem a parte de fazer o programa esperar eu não tenho ideia de como poderia ser.
Eu estava pensando em criar uma variável para salvar a cor selecionada, e depois verificar se está certo , alguém tem uma dica?

---

edit:

Eu criei um jogo em que ele cria uma sequencia de cores e essa sequencia é adicionado em um "List",depois mostra a sequencia piscando os botões em um swing com 4 botoes (azul, vermelho, verde, amarelo)

agora, a parte que eu preciso fazer e que não estou conseguindo é a parte do jogador, ele precisa selecionar as cores na ordem certa, porem eu me perdi por ai, não sei como faz para o programa esperar receber os cliques do jogador,minha ideia, eu teria que fazer um while(true) e quando o botão for pressionado ele sai desse while e salva a cor em uma variável? Não sei qual a forma correta de se fazer isso. Sou bem iniciante em java.

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito ampla. Como vi que está aprendendo(pela sua outra pergunta), seria mais interessante você primeiro tentar entender os fundamentos da linguagem(caso esteja começando agora) antes de cair num projeto desses, que pode ter um nivel de complexidade que pode até atrapalhar seu aprendizado.

Comment: sim, a outra pergunta foi bem estranha, as vezes eu confundo varias coisas, e tenho dificuldade com isso, vou ter que estudar bem essa parte, porem tenho um trabalho para entregar, poderia dar uma olhada de novo? eu editei a pergunta.

Comment: A pergunta continua ampla. No swing não há necessidade de fazer loop para esperar ação do usuário, o funcionamento da API é ficar sob uma thread em execução o tempo todo, com o conceito de listeners, que ficam "ouvindo" ações sobre a interface(desde que você tenha programado alguma, claro)

Comment: Você pode começar vendo algumas perguntas sob a tag [swing](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing), pra ver como ela funciona, pegar algumas soluções e ir brincando com elas, pra ver criar mais afinidade com a API, e dai sim, começar a fazer isso, será bem mais construtivo, porque você estará mexendo em algo que já tem certo conhecimento de como funciona, mesmo que seja um conhecimento básico.

Comment: Hm eu entendi, estava vendo pelo lado errado. Farei o que você disse, tenho muito tempo livre, e isso vai me ajudar.  Muito obrigado.